# How to click all elements available in gallery view using selenium java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I need to click all the available elements in gallery view. When you look at the attached screenshot , it has 2 rows and 8 elements(thumbnail image). I need to click all those elements using selenium java . How I can do that?

I have used following code. do we have any enter [image]other way to click all available elements.

```
List<WebElement> elementName = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class="views-view-grid-horizontal-cols-3-welcomefix"]/div[1]/div[2]/div"));
        for (int i = 0; i < elementName.length(); i++)
                                                     
        {
         elementName[i].click();
                                             
        }
```

In the screenshot,
red color marked locator, give all available elements( i.e all rows, all elements)
blue color marked one identify first row
black color marked one identify 1st row 1st element

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
length() is undefine for the List interface you can use size()

((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", 
Webelement_name);

Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement("WebElement_name").click().perform();

new
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions
.elementToBeClickable(webelement_name)).click();

there are numerous ways to click on the element, few of them listed 
above just make the enhancement as per your convinence
```